# Determining which network user has a file on a network share open

Tags: windows-7

My company has Windows SMB shares running on an Isolon cluster.  Sporadically, possibly after a period of inactivity, a file will erroneously appear as in use by 'another user'.
The problem first showed up with Word and Excel files, and an easy workaround is to copy the file in Windows and work from the copy.

Unfortunately, now the problem is happening to Revit, on a project with multiple file interdependencies, and multiple users don't know that they're going to lose work until they're all hours into it.
Local-PC utilities like Unlocker and FileHunter indicate that the file has no locks.  I restart and attempt to rename the file in Windows, and Windows reports "Document is open by Revit." when the document is not open, on any PC.

What tool(s) can I use to conclusively determine what has a file locked?

Answer (score 4):

You can check in in computer management:

You can access it from the command line with `compmgmt.msc` or go to Start -> right click `computer` and choose "Manage".

Then check open sessions, it will be here:

[image]

Comment: `fsmgmt.msc` is another console which has just "Shared Folders".

Answer (score 2):

Use `net file` or [`psfile`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897552.aspx) on the command line. (`net session` may help too)